# Get Data Type Mismatch error when using Replace Function in WHERE clause of MS Access Update statement

Tags: sql, replace, ms-access-2013

I'm getting the error message "Data type mismatch in criteria expression" with the following UPDATE statement executing in MS Access 2013.

```
UPDATE tblTasks 
   SET tblTasks.IconFilePath = "C:\Images\john.smith.jpg"
 WHERE (((Replace([PersonResponsible]," ",""))="Smith,John") 
   AND ((Len([PersonResponsible]))>0));
```

When I remove the **Replace** function call from the WHERE clause the statement executes without error.

The Data Type of the **PersonResponsible** field is **Short Text(255)**.  I have tried wrapping the the Replace call in CStr and also NZ but still got the data type mismatch error.

Any thoughts are appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Can we see the *John Smith* data line to reproduce issue on our end?

Comment: HI sorry I'm not following that question.  "Smith,John" is quite literally what is being passed in the query.  I must be missing something.  Can you elaborate on that request for the "John Smith data line"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If [PersonResponsible] allows nulls, change your SQL to:

```
UPDATE tblTasks 
   SET tblTasks.IconFilePath = "C:\Images\john.smith.jpg"
 WHERE (((Replace(Nz([PersonResponsible],"")," ",""))="Smith,John") 
   AND ((Len(Nz([PersonResponsible],"")))>0));
```

But really, you can simplify this to:

```
UPDATE tblTasks 
   SET tblTasks.IconFilePath = "C:\Images\john.smith.jpg"
 WHERE (((Replace(Nz([PersonResponsible],"")," ",""))="Smith,John"));
```

The extra where clause doesn't add any more specificity in this case.

Comment: Can't believe I am just now learning about the Nz function, what a life saver!